# SQL - how to create composite primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on creating a composite primary. I want to make a combination of attributes as primary key while creating a table. I am working on Oracle 10g database and SQL as querying language.

Comment: show us some of your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table foo
(
   col_one integer not null,
   col_two integer not null,
   some_other_column varchar(100) not null, 
   constraint pk_foo primary key (col_one, col_two)
);
```

More details and examples in the manual:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2095331
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#CJAEDFIB